# The norm on tensor product

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Here is a quotation of a book:

> Let $B, ~C$ be unital C*-algebras and $A$ be a nonunital C*-algebra, $\|\cdot\|_{\alpha}$ be a C*-norm on $B\odot C$ (the tensor product) and $\|\cdot\|_{\beta}$ be the C*-norm on $A\odot C$ obtained by restricting $\|\cdot\|_{\alpha}$ to $A\odot C \subset B\odot C$.
>
> Let $A_{1}=A+\mathbb{C}1_{B}$ and note that $A\odot C\subset B\otimes_{\alpha} C$. Hence $\|\cdot\|_{\beta}$ extends to a norm which yields an inclusion $A\otimes_{\beta} C\subset A_{1}\otimes_{\beta} C$. (Here, "$\otimes_{\alpha}$" denotes the completion of $\odot$ with the norm $\|\cdot\|_{\alpha}$).

I can not comprehend that " **$\|\cdot\|_{\beta}$ extends to a norm which yields an inclusion $A\otimes_{\beta} C\subset A_{1}\otimes_{\beta} C$"**. Why can the $\|\cdot\|_{\beta}$ on $A\odot C$ be extended to $A_{1}\odot C$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can take $\|\cdot\|_\alpha$. This is a norm on $A_1\odot C$ that agrees with $\|\cdot\|_\beta$ on $A\odot C$.

Comment: Do you mean $||.||_{\alpha}$ restrict on $A_{1}\odot C$ is still $||.||_{\beta}$?

Comment: No. $\|\cdot\|_\beta$ is the restriction of $\|\cdot\|_\alpha$ to $A\odot C$. If you restrict $\|\cdot\|_\alpha$ to $A_1\odot C$, then you obtain a norm on $A_1\odot C$ that, when restricted to $A\odot C$, agrees with $\|\cdot\|_\beta$.

Comment: Oh, I am in chaos. So what does the $A_{1}\otimes C$ mean here?

Comment: $A_1\odot C$ is the set of elements of the form $\sum a_j\otimes c_j$, with $a_j\in A_1$, $c\in C$. And $A_1=A+\mathbb C\,1_B$, as defined in your question.

Comment: So the $A_{1}\otimes_{\beta} C$ is the completion of $A \odot C$ with the norm $||.||_{\beta}$? But $||.||_{\beta}$ is just the restriction of $||.||_{\alpha}$ on $A\odot C$, not $A_{1}\odot C$.

Comment: They are just using the same name $\|\cdot\|_\beta$ for the restriction of $\|\cdot\|_\alpha$ to $A_1\odot C$.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Thanks.